What can semigroup theory do better in the study of PDEs compared to alternative methods?
I've recently come across semigroup theory in my mathematical physics class and while the theory itself feels nice to work with, I have not yet understood what does the theory offer for the study of PDEs, that other methods do not provide? To be clear, semigroup theory does not have to provide anything groundbreaking, and in mathematics abstractions and connections to other fields are more than sufficient to justify the study of a set subject X. Still, while I have been skimming other books and lecture notes on the subject, many authors begin their exposition by stating something along the lines of: "The expressive power and usefulness of semigroup theory can not be understated in the study of XYZ." For this reason I am interested in knowing more about any of the following situations
1.) semigroup theory provides tools that almost trivializes the question at hand;
2.) semigroup theory is the "best" (in some sense) known method to attack the given problem;
3.) semigroup theory provides stronger/better results than other existence/uniqueness etc. machinery of PDEs;
4.) in the case of books/lecture notes (diclaimer: this is a complete shot in the dark), semigroup theory requires significantly less tools and results to prove something meaningful about the PDEs at hand compared to other alternatives;
5.) semigroup theory helps to shorten and/or demystify known proofs
I appreciate all relevant examples/references!

I have not yet understood what does the theory offer for the study of PDEs, that other methods do not provide?
A very important aspect is study of the asymptotic behavior by estimating the resolvent operator. Under appropriate assumptions, if $A$ generates a C$_0$-semigroup of contractions on a Hilbert space and $i\mathbb R\subset\rho(A)$:

(Polynomial decay) If you want to show that the solution of the problem $U_t=AU$ satisfies $\|U(t)\|\leq C t^{-1/\alpha}$, it is enough to show that $\|(i\beta I-A)^{-1}\|\leq M|\beta|^\alpha$ for all $|\beta|$ large enough.

(Exponential decay) If you want to show that the solution of the problem $U_t=AU$ satisfies $\|U(t)\|\leq C e^{-\alpha t}$, it is enough to show that $\|(i\beta I-A)^{-1}\|\leq M$ for all $|\beta|$ large enough.


In both cases, $C$ depends on the initial data. The first statement is an application of the Borichev-Tomilov Theorem. The second one is an application of the Gearhart-Prüss Theorem.

Thanks! Could you by any chance give some references for those two results?

@CartesianBear For the Gearhart-Prüss Theorem, as introductory reading, I would recommend this paper (available at arxiv). Note that [10] and [18] are the original works; also, reference [9] (which I mentioned in this other answer of mine) is a very good one. An example of application can be seen in Section 2.2 of this book.

@CartesianBear With respect to the Borichev-Tomilov Theorem, it is a "recent" result and I am not aware of any work that addresses it in a general/introductory way. So I can only suggest the original paper (also available at arxiv, Theorem 2.4).
